# UInt8 is not convertible to CGFloat error in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am a beginner level programmer in iOS app development using Swift. Now I am facing the compile time issue "UInt8 is not convertible to CGFloat"

```
var numberOfAvatars:Int = 8
let count:Int = 1
let columns:Int = 3
let dimension:CGFloat = 84.0
var spacing:CGFloat = (avatarContentcroll.frame.size.width - columns * dimension)/(columns+1)
var scHeight:CGFloat = spacing + (numberOfAvatars/columns) * (dimension + spacing)
```

I've tried all the solutions out there and did many experiments. And I am not sure why still I am getting this error.

Comment: Swift doesn't implicitly type cast for you when you try to perform operations on Int/CGFloat/etc. You need to either cast as necessary, or make all your variables the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it explicitly  as

```
var spacing:CGFloat = CGFloat((avatarContentcroll.frame.size.width) - CGFloat(columns) * (dimension))/(columns+1)
var scHeight:CGFloat = CGFloat(spacing + (CGFloat(numberOfAvatars)/CGFloat(columns)) * (dimension + spacing))
```

or you can try converting every expression in CGFloat

```
var spacing:CGFloat = ((avatarContentcroll.frame.size.width) - CGFloat(columns) * (dimension))/(columns+1)
var scHeight:CGFloat = spacing + (CGFloat(numberOfAvatars)/CGFloat(columns)) * (dimension + spacing)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must explicitly cast your `Int`s as `CGFloat`s (via `as`), or construct them -- like so:

```
var spacing:CGFloat = ((avatarContentcroll.frame.size.width) - CGFloat(columns) * (dimension))/(columns+1)
var scHeight:CGFloat = spacing + (CGFloat(numberOfAvatars)/CGFloat(columns)) * (dimension + spacing)
```